# calculate hexadecimal offset within array

Tags: c, arrays, hex, offset

I know in general what  offsets are, but I have a question regarding offsets on the following array. Let's say I have a uint8 array:

```
   const myArray uint8[]=
   {
   0xCB, 0xF8, 0xFA, 0xFB, 0xCA, 0xAC, 0x24, 0x53, 0x64, 0x4F, 0x1E, 0xA2, 
   0xF9, 0x78, 0xCA, 0x63, 0xB8, 0x7F, 0xFC, 0xFB, 0xD8, 0xFA, 0xFB, 0x8F, 
   0x67, 0xC1, 0xFD, 0xF8, 0xC2, 0xF8, 0xFF, 0xF9, 0xFA, 0xE4, 0xFA, 0xF9,
   0xFB, 0xFE, 0xE4, 0xFA, 0xCA, 0xCF, 0x94, 0xD5, 0xD6, 0xCA, 0xA2, 0xA2,
   ....
   ....
   ....
   ....
}
```

Now I have description which says:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Offset in myArray | meaning     |  size (Byte) |
--------------------------------------------------
|    0x00           |  Version     |  1          |
-------------------------------------------------
|    0x01           |  Timestamp  |  15         |
 ------------------------------------------------
|    0x10           |  Info1      |   8         |
 ------------------------------------------------
|    0x18           |  Info2      |   2         |
 ------------------------------------------------
```

Does this in myArray mean:

For offset 0x00: It's the element with index 0 of myArray, so 0xCB

For offset 0x01: It's the element with index 1..9,so 0xF8, 0xFA, 0xFB, 0xCA, 0xAC, 0x24, 0x53, 0x64, 0x4F

etc.

Or do I interpret it wrong?

Comment: Thats correct..

Comment: I don't understand how you came up with `1..9` for the field `Timestamp`; it's size is specified as 15 so the relevant elements should be 15 and not 9, i.e. it's `0xF8, 0xFA, 0xFB, 0xCA, 0xAC, 0x24, 0x53, 0x64, 0x4F, 0x1E, 0xA2, 0xF9, 0x78, 0xCA, 0x63`.

Comment: Almost, but you forget the *size*. And that the offsets are presented in *hexadecimal*. So that means the "Info1" field *starts* at `myArray[16]` (i.e. `myArray[0x10]`).

Comment: Almost correct. The second field is 15 bytes long and goes from 0x01 .. 0x0F, not 0x09

Comment: Incorrect because for offset 0x01, it's elements from 0x01 up to 0x10 in hexadecimal basis (size is 15, hexa 0xF), so elements 0xF8, 0xFA..., 0xCA, 0x63.

Comment: I'd look into mapping that data to a struct. Either by disabling padding or by de-serialization.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I misinterpreted some stuff :)

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Nearly correct. It is 0x01..0x0F, not 0x10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elements have a given size, as described by your size column. So basically what this tells you is:

**Version** starts at offset **0x00** (aka, position 0) and has a size of 1, so its the first element: **0xCB**

**Timestamp** starts at offset **0x01** (aka, position 1) and has a size of 15, so its the combined elements: **[0xF8, 0xFA, 0xFB, 0xCA, 0xAC, 0x24, 0x53, 0x64, 0x4F, 0x1E, 0xA2, 0xF9, 0x78, 0xCA, 0x63]**

**Info1** starts at offset **0x10** (aka, position 16) and has a size of 8, so its the combined elements: **[0xB8, 0x7F, 0xFC, 0xFB, 0xD8, 0xFA, 0xFB, 0x8F]**

**Info2** starts at offset 0x18 (aka, position 24) and has a size of 2, so its the combined elements: **[0x67, 0xC1]**

And so it goes...

One thing that you seem to be getting wrong in your analysis, as others have pointed out is that the offsets are in base 16 (hexadecimal). So 0x10 is 1 * 16 + 0 = 16.

How to interpret each byte sequence as a proper type is up to you.

Does this make sense?